# How can I access Azure Blob Storage using JS in the browser

Tags: javascript, azure, azure-blob-storage

I'm trying to access Azure Blob Storage in a web app (Vue).
However, I get the following error:

> catch: Account connection string is only supported in Node.js environment

How can I access Azure Blob Storage?
I investigated, but I was not sure what the cause was.
Can anyone please tell me?

---

code.vue

```js
const { BlobServiceClient } = require("@azure/storage-blob");

mounted: function () {
  this.init()
},
methods: {
  init: function () {
    this.accessBlob()
        .then(() => console.log('Done'))
        .catch((ex) => console.log('catch:', ex.message));
    },
  accessBlob: async function(){
      const config = require("./config/config.json");
      const AZURE_STORAGE_CONNECTION_STRING = config.storageAccountOrConnectionString;

      const blobServiceClient = await BlobServiceClient.fromConnectionString(AZURE_STORAGE_CONNECTION_STRING);
      console.log(blobServiceClient);
    }
  }
```

Comment: It's pretty much what the error says. Your code runs in the browser but the method of connection you're trying to use is not supported in a web environment

Comment: Thank you for teaching.  
In this case, how can I improve access to Azure Blob Storage from vue.js?  
I would appreciate it if you could tell me.

Answer (score 3):

According to the [official document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/@azure/storage-blob/blobserviceclient?view=azure-node-latest#fromconnectionstring-string--storagepipelineoptions-), when use the the menthod`BlobServiceClient.fromConnectionString` to connect Azure blob, the account connecting string just can be used in the **NODE.JS** runtime.
[image]

So I suggest us use the sas token connect Azure blob storage. For example

1. Create sas token(I use sdk `crypto-js` to create it)

```
import * as CryptoJS from 'crypto-js';

 const accountName =environment.accountName;
  const key=environment.key;
  const start = new Date(new Date().getTime() - (15 * 60 * 1000));
  const end = new Date(new Date().getTime() + (30 * 60 * 1000));
const signedpermissions = 'rwdlac';
  const signedservice = 'b';
  const signedresourcetype = 'sco';
  const signedexpiry = end.toISOString().substring(0, end.toISOString().lastIndexOf('.')) + 'Z';
  const signedProtocol = 'https';
  const signedversion = '2018-03-28';

  const StringToSign =
      accountName+ '\n' +
      signedpermissions + '\n' +
      signedservice + '\n' +
      signedresourcetype + '\n' +
       '\n' +
      signedexpiry + '\n' +
       '\n' +
      signedProtocol + '\n' +
signedversion + '\n';

 var str =CryptoJS.HmacSHA256(StringToSign,CryptoJS.enc.Base64.parse(key));
 var sig = CryptoJS.enc.Base64.stringify(str);


  const sasToken =`sv=${(signedversion)}&ss=${(signedservice)}&srt=${(signedresourcetype)}&sp=${(signedpermissions)}&se=${encodeURIComponent(signedexpiry)}&spr=${(signedProtocol)}&sig=${encodeURIComponent(sig)}`;
```

2. Connect Azure Blob

```
import {
BlobServiceClient
  AnonymousCredential,
  newPipeline
} from "@azure/storage-blob";



const pipeline = newPipeline(new AnonymousCredential());
 const blobServiceClient =new BlobServiceClient(`https://${accountname}.blob.core.windows.net?${sasToken}`,
                                                             pipeline  )
```

Comment: Could you explain why/if the method you are using to generated the sas token is different from this: https://github.com/Azure-Samples/functions-node-sas-token/blob/master/GetSasToken-Node/index.js ? - Thanks.