Downloading file from Azure Blob Storage from a React-Native application
I want to connect to azure blob storage via my React-Native Application.
I am getting this error: [Error: Account connection string is only supported in Node.js environment]
Does this mean that I cannot connect to Azure using connection string in react-native application?
Please provide alternatives to do so.
    import { BlobServiceClient} from "@azure/storage-blob";

    const downloadfirmwareFile=async()=>{
        try{
            const blobServiceClient=BlobServiceClient.fromConnectionString(azureConnectionString)
            const containerClient=blobServiceClient.getContainerClient(azureContainerName)
            const blobClient=containerClient.getBlobClient({filepath}) //exact location where the file is stored
            const downloadedBlobResponse= await blobClient.download(0)
            const downloadedBlob= await downloadedBlobResponse.blobBody
            if(!downloadedBlob){
                console.log("Blob data is undefined")
                return;
            }
            else{
                const arrayBuffer= await downloadedBlob.arrayBuffer()
                const binaryData= Buffer.from(arrayBuffer).toString()
                const filePath=`${RNFS.DocumentDirectoryPath}/downloaded-file.bin`
                await RNFS.writeFile(filePath,binaryData,'binary')
                console.log("file created")
            }
        }
        catch(error){
            console.log(error)
        }
    }

I expected this code in react-native to connect with azure blob storage and download the file from there but unfortunately does not do that.

Hope this helps: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61314287/how-can-i-access-azure-blob-storage-using-js-in-the-browser

@Nouphal.M should this code which uses crypto be used in the Client-Side apps like react-native apps?

@FreyalShah Can you try with the SAS token once?

I got the same error with the Azure Storage connection string in my environment.
ERROR  Error downloading blob: [Error: Account connection string is only supported in Node.js environment]
ERROR  Download error: [Error: Account connection string is only supported in Node.js environment]


@Nouphal.M Thanks for the comment.
As mentioned in this SO thread, BlobServiceClient.fromConnectionString won't work in Node.js runtime.
So, I used the Azure storage Blob SAS URL in the React-Native code to download a blob from a container.
Here is the complete code with the Blob SAS URL.
Code :
src/App.js :
import React from 'react';
import { SafeAreaView, Text, StyleSheet } from 'react-native';
import DownloadButton from './components/DownloadButton';
const App = () => {
    const sasUrl = '<blobSASURL>';
    return (
        <SafeAreaView style={styles.container}>
            <Text style={styles.title}>Azure Blob Storage Example</Text>
            <DownloadButton sasUrl={sasUrl} />
        </SafeAreaView>
    );
};
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
        flex: 1,
        justifyContent: 'center',
        alignItems: 'center',
    },
    title: {
        fontSize: 24,
        fontWeight: 'bold',
    },
});
export default App;

src/services/AzureBlobService.js :
import RNFetchBlob from 'rn-fetch-blob';
const downloadFileFromBlobStorage = async (sasUrl) => {
    try {
        const response = await RNFetchBlob.config({
            fileCache: true,
            appendExt: 'bin',
        }).fetch('GET', sasUrl);
        const statusCode = response.info().status;
        if (statusCode !== 200) {
            throw new Error(`Failed to download blob: ${statusCode}`);
        }
        const filePath = response.path(); 
        console.log('File downloaded successfully:', filePath);
        return filePath;    } catch (error) {
        console.error('Error downloading blob:', error);
        throw error; 
    }
};
export { downloadFileFromBlobStorage };

src/components/DownloadButton.js :
import React from 'react';
import { TouchableOpacity, Text, Alert, StyleSheet } from 'react-native';
import { downloadFileFromBlobStorage } from '../services/AzureBlobService';
const DownloadButton = ({ sasUrl }) => {
    const handleDownload = async () => {
        try {
            const filePath = await downloadFileFromBlobStorage(sasUrl);
            Alert.alert('File Downloaded', `File saved at: ${filePath}`);
        } catch (error) {
            Alert.alert('Error', 'Failed to download file. Please try again later.');
            console.error('Download error:', error);
        }
    };
    return (
        <TouchableOpacity style={styles.button} onPress={handleDownload}>
            <Text style={styles.buttonText}>Download File</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
    );
};
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    button: {
        backgroundColor: '#1E90FF',
        padding: 10,
        borderRadius: 5,
        marginTop: 20,
    },
    buttonText: {
        color: '#fff',
        fontWeight: 'bold',
        fontSize: 16,
        textAlign: 'center',
    },
});
export default DownloadButton;

Output :
I ran the above React-Native code with the below command.
npx react-native run-android


I got the below page in my emulator and clicked on Download File button as below,

The blob downloaded successfully as below,

Logs :

